# Why is my store.html not recognized?

Tags: django

I am Learning Django Udemy course(James Carrigan),I only updated to 2.0.5

```
tree bookstore
bookstore
├── bookstore
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── store
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   ├── store.html
    │   └── template.html
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

These are my views

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'template.html')

def store(request):
    return render(request,'store.html')
```

Urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from store import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index ,name='index' ),
    url(r'^store', views.store ,name='store' ),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I have changed line in HTML Boilerplate file

```
<p>Welcome to mystery books and store template is changed!</p>
```

I have problem when I go runserver
[image]

It does not see any difference between 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/store and
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index

Why is my other html not recognized?

Comment: What if you restart the server?

Comment: I got the same.I will add tree structure.

Comment: Have you tried visiting your page in Incognito mode? That should force the browser to not show a cached version of the page.

Comment: How to go incognito,I have changed from Chrome to Firefox I got the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't end your regex pattern, so the first one matches everything.
Make sure you end your regex expression with `$`

```
url(r'^$', views.index ,name='index' ),
url(r'^store$', views.store ,name='store' ),
```